# Multiplication issue on spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

When multiplying two columns on a spreadsheet the product is off by $0.03; both over and under, without any apparent consistency, how can I solve this?

Comment: Without the multiplication and exact numbers (and formulas) we can't begin to check.

Comment: 30 9 $40.67 $366.00-these are the entries in columns F,G,H & I respectively. Column H has a formula =IF(F25=30,'Route Pay and Miles'!$Q$27," ") and column G has the formula =IF($F25=30,G25*'Route Pay and Miles'!$Q$27," ")

Comment: Maybe you can [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/657074/edit) your question with the correct information like formulas and numbers. Without knowing `*'Route Pay and Miles'!$Q$27` we can't be sure of anything. Maybe that number is "off" (and has internally more than 2 decimals, while only displaying two or so) How is that number on `'Route Pay and Miles'!$Q$27` calculated?

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving just a shot in the dark here (until you provide other exact numbers of the cells):

When multiplying (and dividing) numbers and you see (and expect) on screen 2 decimals and you want to do further calculations with 2 decimals you should **always** use the `ROUND()` function. Internally these numbers could be different. On screen you could see `0.34` but internally this could be `0,335643564`. When doing further calculations with this cell the internal number (`0,335643564`) will be used.

You have two options. Do a `ROUND()` around your cell value or formula on `'Route Pay and Miles'!$Q$27` or do the round in your other formula. i.e. `=IF($F25=30,G25*ROUND('Route Pay and Miles'!$Q$27,2)," ")` where the `,2` are the expected decimals.

Comment: Thank you, adding the ROUND function seems to have solved the issue...

Comment: Glad i could help! Please remember to accept an answer if you found it helpful. You can click the big checkbox left of an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason in any particular case could indeed be numbers like the example in `Rik`'s answer and number formatting that displays decimals less than those existing in the value. And `ROUND` does indeed offer a way forward (though sometimes not a desirable one).

However, there is a different, rather "insidious" reason one encounters such a thing. That is the convention Excel uses for performing arithmetic using decimal numbers in a binary computer world. One seldom notices these differences as they take place in the 15th significant digit of the value. So an entered number will be precisely the value entered, but the moment any arithmetic is performed, two "perfect" numbers may (or may not, usually "not") give a non-perfect result. So 1+5 may give 6.00000000000002 for a result.

It is NOT fixable. Even though Excel internally uses 27-28 digits and could force these errors away, they follow the convention chosen in 1985 and do not. Intriguingly though, it seems they now (2023) make some of the extra accuracy recoverable. Not that it really matters in spreadsheets, but interesting.

The solution to this is also to use the `ROUND` group of functions or the `TRUNC` function when would matter that the inaccuracies exist in component values or a single result. Normally this will not be so, but especially for comparisons, it matters a lot.

Another, less ideal (usually) method would be to go into the program options and set the option to use `Precision As Displayed` so that your, ordinarily, formatted to some lower precision than Excel will give, will take care of truncating for you. Since you'd have to keep changing back and forth for the one spreadsheet it is needed on, it could lead to... difficulties. But it might be handy in, say, work involving money, especially payroll. One could always open a new instance of Excel to work on such spreadsheets, remembering to set the option before opening the spreadsheet/s. Test though to make sure it does not somehow affect other instances of Excel you have running before doing it with real files. ("Second instance" means a new running version of Excel, one that, to the other running instance would look like any other "not-it" program. It specifically does NOT mean just opening a new window or anything equivalent.)